# Facebook Remove User From APP

Tags: php, facebook, http-delete

I have built a login system using FB Login JS SDK. Now theres a link to delete the account from my website, from database I am able to delete that users detail, but I also want that my app to be removed from that users app lists.

I searched a lot and found that by sending DELETE method, we can do that. I tried below code:

```
$delete_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/" . $user->fb_id . "?method=delete&access_token=MY_ACCESS_TOKEN";
$ch = curl_init($delete_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "DELETE");
$response = curl_exec($ch);
echo var_dump($response);
```

But this always returns me with error:

> {"error":{"message":"(#100) Can only call this method on valid test
>   users for your app","type":"OAuthException","code":100}}

Is this a correct way to delete? Or is there some other way?

Comment: Is your app in `sandmode`?

Comment: no its not in sandmode